# Mongoose returns undefined on a field with existing data

Tags: node.js, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

So I'm trying to associate GridFS collection with schema containing some of the data in it and then populating it with another model.

**GridFS Schema:**

```js
const gfsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    filename: String
  }, {strict: false});
const GridFs = conn.model('GridFs', gfsSchema, 'posters.files');
```

**Code used:**

```js
GridFs.find({}, (err, files) => {
  console.log(files);
  console.log(files.filename);
});
```

The first `console.log` returns what I expected:

```
[ { _id: 5da3a37a6587f015783637d0,
    length: 3917314,
    chunkSize: 261120,
    uploadDate: 2019-10-13T22:21:54.389Z,
    filename: 'ed49b55f58b1d5ea06ba95f18852e2a3.png',
    md5: '9b52103d5c6f671023290d87b106c9cf',
    contentType: 'image/png' } ]
```

But the second one returns `undefined`, even though the example above shows there's existing data in the `filename` field.

I need `filename` field in order to visualize images when populating.

Comment: `files` is an array so it should be `files[0].filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

files is an array so you need to call it like

```
files[0].filename
```

if your required filename is at first place, else you can use index according to requirement

Comment: That did work. Thank you very much for the help @Savan Padaliya, Cuong Le Ngoc.